# Why does scalac infer `Foo with Bar` not just `Foo` for match/case return type?

Tags: scala, traits

In a model class, I have a simple `getter` function like so:

```
  def geoLoc = {
    geoQuant match {
      case "COUNTRY" => Country.find.byId(geoLocId)
      case "PROVICE" => Province.find.byId(geoLocId.toLong)
      case "CITY" => City.find.byId(geoLocId.toLong)
      case "STREET" => Street.find.byId(geoLocId.toLong)
    }
  }
```

The idea being to get the GeoLocation of the object – which can be of either of the four types. From what I see, the function `geoLoc` has a return type that is the super class of all: the `Country`, `Province`, `City` & `Street` – which extend the `Model` class.

Instead the function's return type is `Model with GeoEntity`, where `GeoEntity` is a trait each of these classes have along with `Model`.

Why does that happen? What can I do to make the function return specific types with pattern matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala infers the most specific type it can. Each of the four instances is both a `Model` and a `GeoEntity`, so that's the inferred type: `Model with GeoEntity`. If you want the function to return the less specific type of `Model` (all `Model with GeoEntity`s are `Model`s, but not all `Models` are `Model with GeoEntity`s), just annotate the function with that type: `def geoLoc: Model = ...`.

The function can only have one return type and there's no way to know at compile time which of the four cases it will hit. If you want to return a more specific type for each case, then the information as to which type this object has needs to be part of the object type (or you could use dependent typing, but the type information still has to come from somewhere). E.g. you could make your object an abstract generic type, with subclasses for the specific instances:

```
class MyObject[LocationType <: Model] {
  def geoLoc: LocationType
}
class MyObjectCountry extends MyObject[Country] {
  def geoLoc: Country = ...
}
class MyObjectProvice extends MyObject[Province] {
  def geoLoc: Province = ...
}
```